# Help Center doesn't play well with text zoom

Tags: bug, design, help-center

The spiffy new Help Center presents an attractive, easy-to-use layout, but the page doesn't adapt to text zoom as well as the rest of the site does.  This is the page with three levels of zoom (my usual for reading Mi Yodeya):

[image: Help page with text zoom]

(Firefox 18.0.1, Windows XP.)

The overlapping text (and button) in the first column is particularly problematic.  Yeah, the text also spills out of the bounding box in the "how it works" section, but that's merely an issue of attractiveness, while the overlapping text impedes function.  Both matter, but the latter matters more.

As I said, the rest of the site works pretty well with my text zoom; there are some glitches, but the main page adjusts itself so question titles and tags don't overlap, text doesn't spill into the right-side links, and so on.  It's just this one page where I'm seeing a bigger problem.

Comment: Yikes. That's not very pretty. I'll have someone take a look at it. Looks fine in Chrome and Safari on Mac, must be a Windows issue.

Comment: Thanks @Laura.  I forgot to check on my Mac at home.

Comment: Unfortunately, we've been unable to reproduce this problem. Have you tried updating your browser and seeing if that fixes the zoom issue? We don't typically support more than one previous version of any browser, so sometimes we just don't have the resources to make everything work on all browsers and OSs.

Comment: @Laura, thanks for following up.  I'm on the latest Firefox our IT department supports.  If this isn't happening to anyone else, then I agree it's not very important.  (I don't have this problem at home but I don't know what makes the difference -- newer Firefox, MacOS, or some other difference of which I'm unaware.)  WHen I posted I thought it was a broader problem.